# Why does a CONSTANT give me errors when used in a subscript?

Tags: c

For example, I have the following code:

```
#define MAX_CLIENTS 100;

void main() {
    char* pick[MAX_CLIENTS];
    int* points[MAX_CLIENTS];
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile it throws these errors:

```
file.c:4: error: expected ‘]’ before ‘;’ token
file.c:5: error: expected ‘]’ before ‘;’ token
```

If I replace MAX_CLIENTS in the subscripts with a literal `100`, then the errors are gone.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `;` in `#define MAX_CLIENTS 100;` is redundant , remove it and you should be fine.

Remember that `#define` is a pre-processor command, that replaces `MAX_CLIENTS` with `100;` - you don't want the semicolon there, only the 100.

Comment: Lol, doh! I can accept your answer in 12 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the trailing semi-colon on your define, which causes the macro to expand to

```
char* pick[100;];
//            ^-- cause of compiler errors
```

Remove the semi-colon from your define and all should be well.

Answer (score 2):

it should be :

```
#define MAX_CLIENTS 100
```

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor directives shouldn't end with a semicolon..

It becomes a statement if you do so..

Removing the semicolon at the end of the macro helps you..